# Margin bottom is not working for Ad Space

Tags: css

My ad space is coming on Category links. I tried using margin-buttom:40px to push above Category links, but not working, while margin-top:20px is working to push it more down. Is there any way to push adcode above category links??

Note:- Sample image ad is working fine... but problem is in when (Adsense) a fixed height/width added to the code !!

Problem Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKoZC.jpg

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ba5syxqc/

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="header-space" style="height:90px;width:728px;display:inline-block;float:right;margin-bottom-20px;background-color:#ff0000">
                                        <div class="textwidget"><p><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><br />
<!-- Header 2 for Desktop Only 3 Nov 2018 --><br />
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-92143878EXAMPLE"
     data-ad-slot="732EXAMPLE"></ins><br />
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></p>
</div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because top of the screen is fixed at 0px but bottom could go infinite, you could try to put all of your code in div or try to put margin-top in negative like margin-top:-20px

Comment: Happy to help